# OleDbDataReader to extract data as flat file painfully slow

Tags: c#

I am using the following code to extract data from an Access source to write it as tab separated file line by line.

```
private static void WriteFlatFile(string pathAndFileName, string connString)
{
    if (File.Exists(pathAndFileName))
    {
    File.Delete(pathAndFileName);
    }

    using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString))
    {
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT X, Y, Z FROM SomeAmazingTable", conn);

    conn.Open();

    OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        var newContent = string.Format(
        "{0}\t{1}"
        , reader.GetValue(0).ToString().Trim()
        , reader.GetValue(1).ToString().Trim()
        );

        File.AppendAllText(pathAndFileName, newContent + Environment.NewLine);
    }
    reader.Close();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this is painfully slow. Is there anything I can improve/change?

Comment: It depends on which part is painfully slow (database or actual writing). But to start with, remove `File.AppendAllText` and replace with opening `FileStream` once (outside while loop) and writing there. `File.AppendAllText` opens file every time, writes there, then closes and you don't need that here.

Comment: Thanks! will try this.

Comment: Muuch better - thaanks - feel free to post answer please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you verified that database query is fast - problem is in the way you are writing data to a file. `File.AppendAllText` will open file, append data there, then close the file. This opening and closing in a tight loop can decrease perfomance and is completely unnecessary here. Instead, open file once, outside of while loop, and write there:

```
using (var fs = new StreamWriter(pathAndFileName)) {
    while (reader.Read()) {
        var newContent = string.Format(
            "{0}\t{1}"
            , reader.GetValue(0).ToString().Trim()
            , reader.GetValue(1).ToString().Trim()
        );
        fs.WriteLine(newContent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you not put all data in a string variable with new line information and once you are done with the reading just open the file once and write all data into in one attempt.

```
        string stream = "";
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString))
        {
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT X, Y, Z FROM SomeAmazingTable", conn);

            conn.Open();

            OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var newContent = string.Format(
                "{0}\t{1}"
                , reader.GetValue(0).ToString().Trim()
                , reader.GetValue(1).ToString().Trim()
                );

                stream = newContent + Environment.NewLine;
            }

            File.WriteAllText(pathAndFileName, stream);

            reader.Close();
        }
```

Comment: then you can additionally apply a check on size of data, like if data size in stream variable exceeds 1MB or like that only then you open the file, write data into it and close the file and so on.